# Как в Laravel 5 сделать url с параметрами?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony2

Нужно сделать url с неопределённым количеством параметров, 2 из которых массивы. Хочу так сделать поиск.

Например:

```
kino.com/{category?}/{country?}/{actors?}/{eactors?}
```

А выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
kino.com/komedii/kanada/actors/45/154/eactors/67/99

kino.com/uzhasyi

kino.com/rossiya/eactors/56/87/34
```

1. category - категория
2. country - страна
3. actors - актёры (которые должны быть в фильме), а точнее их id
4. eactors - актёры (которые не должны быть в фильме), а точнее их id

actors и eactors массивы.

Это легко сделать на PHP через get (kino.com?category=komedii&country=kanada и т.д), но как это сделать средствами Laravel и ЧПУ?

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте через get параметры, через ЧПУ рандомное число параметров вам не сделать. Чтобы передавать через get просто не указывайте параметры при инициализации роута

Comment: Параметра всего четыре, просто некоторых может не быть. Основная проблема в actors и eactors, не понятно как реализовать. Сделал так
    `Route::get('/films/{category?}/{country?}/{actors ?}/{eactors?}', 'RecipeController@index')
->where(['actors' => '^actors/[0-9\/]+$', 'eactors' => '^eactors/[0-9\/]+$']);`

Но если url будет таким:

    `test.com/films/france/eactors/2/79/205`

вернёт 404, а так уже нормально:

    `test.com/films/komedii/kanada/actors/45/147/180/eactors/2/79/205`

Comment: необязательный параметр (который с ?) в роутах обычно используется в конце ссылки, а не в середине. Если параметра нет, то разделяющий слеш все равно остается. Т.е. если вы выведете этот url то получите `test.com/films/france//eactors/2/79/205`

Answer (score 0):

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

База про роуты (маршрутизацию) - 3 урок. Перевод там в принципе не нужен, тк. по коду все понятно.
Также роуты затрагиваются в 9, 13 и 18 уроке. Ответ на твой вопрос кажется в 9м.

Рекомендую посмотреть все уроки, 99% обычных задач ты потом легко решишь (ну или будешь помнить где их посмотреть)

Comment: Дело в том что это всё я знаю. В этих уроках даже близка нет к ответу.